# CSS3 selector for attribute that is "has ANY value and is not null or blank"

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, wildcard

I can't seem to find a css3 wildcard for 'any value not null or blank'.

I have a bunch of divs, some of them have an attribute called `data-group-id` but not all. I want to find all divs that have a that attribute, data-group-id`, and is not blank.

So for example I have these divs:

```
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required="1"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required="1"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required></div>
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required data-group-id="55"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required data-group-id="55"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 custom_boxshadow" data-role="mergeSelector" data-required data-group-id="15"></div>
```

As you can see, the last 3 divs have an attribute called `data-group-id`.

I want to have a selector that finds those three elements. Essentially I'm trying to do this logic

```
$parent.find('div[data-role="mergeSelector"][data-group-id="*"]')
```

where * is a wild card saying 'has a value but doesn't matter what the value is'.

Is there a selector that exists to accomplish this? I can't find anything on the internet.

Thanks!

---

Thank you for the help, finished query is as follows:

```
$parent.find('div[data-role="mergeSelector"][data-group-id]:not([data-group-id=‌​""])')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[data-group-id]:not([data-group-id=""])
```

This will select an element that has the attribute, as long as it is not blank.

Comment: Would this match `<div data-group-id></div>`, though?

Comment: For anyone else who might need it my finished query is: `$parent.find('div[data-role="mergeSelector"][data-group-id]:not([data-group-id=""])')`. @Quantastical I just tested that theory and no, it did not select that div even though it has the attribute. Because the attribute is blank the not ignores it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

> ...where `*` is a wild card saying *has a value but doesn't matter what the value is*.

Here you go:

```
div[data-group-id] { ... }
```

From the spec:

> [**6.3.1. Attribute presence and value
>   selectors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)
>
> **[att]**
>
> Represents an element with the `att` attribute, whatever the value of
>   the attribute.

Comment: Maybe the OP wasn't accurate with their word choice, but the question clearly does not want to match if the attribute is not set to anything or an empty string.

Comment: @RuanMendes perhaps, but this answer is very clear about what it does.